pip freeze is generating all env and system packages instead of venv only
I have been using pip freeze -l > requirements.txt to generate project packages but sudenly, it is generating all projects and system packages and it is messing up my code base! i understand what changed but i would glad if someone help me to solve this out! grazie mille
Am using python3, Django framework on ubuntu and pip

Have you activated the virtual environment with souce venv/bin/activate?

What do you see with which pip?

@vahvero yes i did!!! that's the weird thing! cause before it was working like charm!

@Brannon  path, /home/tinox/.local/bin/pip

@tinox, that's the issue. Your system PATH is prioritized such that pips in the build cache (in .local) are referenced in the path before the venv. I had that issue on Arch when I installed Python3.9 from the AUR. I don't remember exactly how I fixed it; I might have changed the path order or cleaned up some build artifacts and cache.

@Brannon let me see if i can fix! thank you
